# Problem with DataAnnotations and MVC1: Required attribute is ignoring the ErrorMessage property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm validating the properties of a linq to sql entity using DataAnnotations, the properties are validating fine but the Required[ErrorMessage="error message"] ErrorMessage attribute is being ignored and instead I'm getting the default error message.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
    [DisplayName("Nombre")]
    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido" )]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido" )]
    [Range( 0, 1000000, ErrorMessage = "Debe insertar un valor entre {1} y 1,000,000" )]
    public decimal Maximum
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido" )]
    [Range( 0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Debe insertar un valor entre {1} y {2}" )]
    public byte Periods
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Same problem here.  I'll be watching this question.  I know it has to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it's a namespace issue.  I just fixed my problem by putting the Metadata "buddy" class into the same namespace as the Model L2S class, even though I thought I had everything referenced properly.  I wanted to put the metadata classes into their own namespace for organizational purposes but it didn't seem to like that.  FWIW, I'm running on .net 3.5, VS 2008, MVC 2 RC.

Comment: Yep, I ran into the namespace issue when I tried to reorganize the files. But that was a whole different issue.

With this one the problem seems to be a binding issue and not necessarily a data validation one.